# Página de ferramentas de moderação perdeu tradução

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

A página de ferramentas de moderação (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools) já estava traduzida mas voltou a ficar em inglês, todas as quatro abas.

Answer (score 1):

Agora voltou a ficar em português.